# How to prove by contradiction that a function of bounded variation is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, proof-explanation, bounded-variation

I would like to prove that a function defined $[a,b]$ of bounded variation is bounded by contradiction : suppose that $f$ is of bounded variation while note bounded and come up with a contradiction. Here is how I have started.

Suppose that $f$ is not bounded : $\forall M\in\mathbb{R}_{+},\exists x\in[a,b] : \lvert f(x)\rvert>M$

Consider the sequence $u_n = n$, then for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we can find an $x_n$ such that $\lvert f(x_n)\rvert> n$.

And then I don't see how to pursue (if this is the good starting point). I would like to consider a partition of $[a,b]$ including these points but I am not sure if it is the right way to prove this.

I would like your help please !

---

**Edit** (Thanks to jro)

Suppose $f$ is not bounded on $[a,b]$ but of bounded variation, that is $V(f) <M$ for some $M\in\mathbb{R}_{+}$.

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we can find $x_n\in[a,b]$ such that $\lvert f(x_n)\rvert>n + \lvert f(x_0)\rvert$.

Now we will show that we can find a partition of $[a,b]$ such that the total variation is not bounded.

We can find $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>M$. Thus we have by using what we have above :

$$
\lvert f(x_n) - f(x_0)\rvert\geq \lvert \lvert f(x_n)\rvert - \lvert f(x_0)\rvert\rvert>n>M
$$

Then for any partition $(x_i)_{i=0}^{N}$ of $[a,b]$ including $x_n$ with $0\leq n\leq N$ we have

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\lvert f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i)\rvert=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\lvert f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i)\rvert + \sum_{i=n}^{N-1}\lvert f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i)\rvert\geq \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\lvert f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i)\rvert
$$

It follows that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\lvert f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i)\rvert\geq\lvert\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}[f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i)]\rvert = \lvert f(x_n) - f(x_0)\rvert > n > M
$$

So we have

$$
V(f) = \sup_{\sigma\in S}\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\lvert f(t_{i+1}) - f(t_i)\rvert\geq \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\lvert f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i)\rvert > M
$$

where the supremum is taking over all the partition, $\sigma$, of $[a,b]$.

Which is not possible by assumption. Thus, we have shown that being of bounded variation for a function on $[a,b]$ is a sufficient condition to be bounded.

Comment: Use that $ |f(x_n) - f(x_0)| > |f(x_n)| - |f(x_0)|$.

Comment: @jro Thanks to your comment I have try something ! Let me know what you think about this please !

Comment: I think what you wrote works out fine, though it could perhaps be shortened a bit by noting that for every $n$, the points $x_0$ and $x_n$ feature in *some* partition of $[a,b]$, so certainly $V(f) \geq |f(x_0) - f(x_n)| \geq M$ by the supremum definition of $V(f)$, from which we can conclude.